# Wrapper for console.log - Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a wrapper for `console.log`.

I found the `.apply` function in Function prototype, but it's giving me errors:

```
function _log() {
    if (opts.debug) console.log.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

`opts.debug` is a key in my config array.

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at :2:13
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (:905:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (:838:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (:694:21)
```

What's wrong with the way I'm trying to do it? And, how to do it right? Thanks.

Comment: JavaScript uses scope binding. This article explains the this keyword in JS very good [The this keyword](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log` expects to be called as a method of `console`, i.e with `console` for the receiver (`this` argument, first parameter to `apply`). Currently you're passing `this` to `apply`, whatever this is (possibly the global object), it's not the `console` object. Use

```
function _log() {
    if (opts.debug) console.log.apply(console, arguments);
//                                    ^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: isn't `this` the `_log` function? Or am I confusing it with something else

Comment: @MightyPork: No, `this` is whatever the `_log` function was called on. In case of `_log()` (a normal function call), it's `undefined` (or the global object in sloppy mode). See also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for details.

Comment: Oh I see. What I meant was if you made "instance" of the function with `new`, right?

Comment: @MightyPork Yes, if you call the function as `new _log()`, then `this` would refer to the newly created instance (but still not to the `_log` function itself).

Answer (score 2):

You are invoking the `console.log` method in an invalid scope, in order to make it work, you have to invoke it in the `console`'s scope:

```
function _log() {
    if (opts.debug) console.log.apply(console, arguments);
}
```

After testing it a couple of times and it seems that @Rob M. is right about his comment. The binding has to be done with the `console` scope.

Comment: Well I don't understand why this worked, but it did.

Comment: You don't have to call it in the `window` scope, you should use `console` as the scope